# Zeros of $f + t g$ goes to the zeros of $g$ as $t \to \infty$?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

Suppose $f, g \in \mathbb C[x]$ with $\deg(f) > \deg(g)$. Without loss of generality, let $\deg(f) = n$ and $\deg(g) = n-1$. I read a statement without proof: If $h(x) = f(x) + t g(x)$ with $t \in [0, \infty)$, the zeros of $h$ will start from the zeros of $f(x)$ ($t=0$) and converge to the zeros of $g$ ($t \to \infty$) and of course, one of them will tend to infinity. Intuitively, I understand this should be true since if $t$ is sufficiently large, the zeros should be the ones of $g(x)$. I am wondering what a rigorous way to argue this point?

Comment: $h(x)$ at the start, with $t=1$ won't have the zeros of $f$. You probably meant $t\in[0,\infty)$

Comment: Intuitively it feels like it would probably be simpler to consider $\lambda f(x)+g(x)$ as $\lambda\to 0$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor: Yes. I meant $t=0$. Thanks.

Comment: @HenningMakholm yeah I noticed (but not soon enough for you to see it :) )

Comment: I think one can complete a rigorous argument using [Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem), with $g(x)$ being the "dog walker" as $x$ goes in a small circle around a root of $g$ and $\frac1t f(x)$ being the "leash". By increasing $t$ we can make the leash short enough for the theorem to apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a$ be a zero of $g$ and take $r>0$ such that $g(z)\ne0$ if $0<|z-a|\le r$. Then, using Rouché-Frobenius, it is possible to prove that for $t$ large enough, $g$ and $f+t\,g$ have the same number of zeros on $\{|z-a|<r\}$. Letting $r\to0$, this shows that $f-t\,g$ has $n-1$ zeroes as close to the zeroes of $g$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give a reference of "Touche-Frobenius"? I have not met this theorem before and google does not lead me to anywhere.

Comment: You mean [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem), right? I can't find any "Touché-Frobenius", though apparently "Rouché-Frobenius" is sometimes the name of [an unrelated theorem connected to Rouché](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem).

Comment: Yes, it was a typo.

Comment: Could you give a few more words on the detail you omitted? I think you mean we look at $|(t-1)g+f - g| = |(t-2)g + f| {\color{red}<} |(t-1) g + f| + |g|$ on the boundary of the disk. But why do we have the strict inequality? Thanks.

Comment: Compare $t\,g$ and $h=f+t\,g$. Then $h-t\,g=f$. Since $\min_{|z-a|=r}|g(z)|>0$, $t$ can be taken large enough to have $|f|<t\,|g|$ on $\{|z-a|=r\}$.